# Angular: iterar en array dentro de array

Tags: array, angular, ngfor

Tengo un arreglo que obtengo mediante API y en el que mediante un ngFor saco la info que necesito. El problema es que algunos datos están dentro de otro array y no sé cómo aceder a ellos. Por ejemplo, necesito acceder a currencies name. He intentado con otro ngFor pero no me funciona ¿De qué manera puede hacerse?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**html**

```
<tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let pais of paises">
         <td>{{ pais.region }}</td>
         <td> {{ pais.name }}</td>
         <td>{{ pais.capital }}</td>
         <td *ngFor="let currencie of pais.currencies">{{ currencie[0].name }}</td>
         <td></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody>
```

**Y en el ts**

```
paises: Paises[] = [];

getPaises(){
    this.paisesService.getAllPaises().subscribe((response) =>{
      this.paises = response
      console.log(response)

    });
```

Gracias

Comment: Anidando otro `ngFor`

Comment: Hola, he anidado otro ngFor de esta manera <td *ngFor="let currencie of pais.currencies">{{ currencie[0].name }}</td> pero me da error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Comment: Quítale el índice `[0]`

Comment: Mil gracias! ahora sí.

Comment: @Lobos Pongan la respuesta como respuesta! :)